# How can I check if there a folder is converted to Application or not in IIS through Powershell on remote servers?

Tags: powershell, iis

I want to check if folders/virtual folders in the IIS are converted to Application or not through Powershell on multiple remote servers. I tried using **Get-WebVirtualDirectory** but I'm getting an empty response.

I've my site structure like this : **IIS:\Sites\Default Web Site\Services\Folder\V4\Task\SomeService** and in this, the SomeService is in folder format on some of the remote servers. I need to check on all the servers if it is still in folder format and later on convert it Application. But Get-WebVirtualDirectory is not giving any errors or results.

I was using this query to get the virtual directory : *Get-WebVirtualDirectory -site 'Default Web Site' -Application Task*

Answer (score 0):

This is a late answer but it may help someone.

Use `Get-WebApplication` function instead of `Get-WebVirtualDirectory`.

Example :

```
Get-WebApplication -site "Default Web Site" -Name "ApplicationName"
```

In your case :

```
if((Get-WebApplication -site "Default Web Site" -Name "Services/Folder/V4/Task/SomeService").Count -gt 0) {
    some stuff...
}
```